# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import on v6

Tags: node.js, canjs

Iam receiving SyntaxError: Unexpected token import even if my node is v6.
What am I missing ? How do I make import Construct from 'can/construct/'; work for me instead of require ?

```
import Construct from 'can/construct/';  // Doesnt work
var Construct = require('can-construct'); // Works for me


var Animal = Construct.extend({
    sayHi: function(){
        console.log("hi")
    }
});

var animal = new Animal()
animal.sayHi();
```

I understand I need to be in ES6 to use import statement. But I already have it .

```
/usr/local/bin/node --version
v6.10.1
```

not sure package.json matters :

```
{
  "name": "canjstest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "canjs.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "Test",
  "dependencies": {
    "canjs": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Import/export isn't supported on Node 6, and I don't think it's even supported correctly in 8 either. You're going to need a transpiler like Babel.

Comment: I did npm install --save babel-cli babel-preset-node6. still same error

Comment: also, npm install --save babel didnt help

Comment: @Victor: You also need to actually use Babel.

Answer (score 2):

ES6 modules are not supported in Node at all. There are some great article ([one](https://nodesource.com/blog/es-modules-and-node-js-hard-choices/), [two](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c)) around why it's been hard to decide how to implement it.

I suggest to transpile your code via babel.

A quick npm script would be:

```
"build:js": "babel src --out-dir dist --presets=es2015 --plugins=transform-runtime,transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
```

While you need the following npm modules:

```
npm i babel-cli babel-plugin-transform-runtime babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Hope that helps